# rvm requirements.. ruby installation on mac os stuck

Tags: ruby, macos, operating-system, homebrew, rvm

I am starting out on ruby and still stuck in installation on mac for past two days.

Following this site for rvm installation..

http://rvm.io

Thereafter tried to install ruby using

```
$ rvm install 3.0.0
```

gives this output

```
Checking requirements for osx.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Error: Calling `brew search` with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use `brew formulae` instead.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system......
Installing required packages: gcc@6, lib.|
```

Thereafter its stuck..
Stuck on this for past two days..  I am on mac os el-capitan.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You probably don't have Xcode command line utilities installed with the license accepted, and are clearly missing the build prerequisites listed.

Comment: Thanks. Installed xcode command line tools.